# Convert Hex dump to ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii, xxd

so i'm wondering if it's possible, using Bash or Python, to convert the following hex code into it's ascii output like it would have in xxd. As i've used OCR to get the text from the following image.

[image]
Is there a way using bash or python that i can convert the following hex dump into ascii characters?

(the hex dump, is only the hex part without the ascii)

```
00000690 52 4D 41 50 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  
000006A0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 E0 01 04 90 9B 00 01   
000006E0 B9 4D E9 46 5B 43 00 10 B2 BA FB 46 BA 24 13 16 
000006F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
00000700 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

With the hopeful output of something approximating the following (except in text form not an image), that is to say, the output of hexdump -C":
[image]

Comment: A "hex dump" is usually already in ASCII. Hex in that case is a visual representation of the number. Do you mean you have a binary file to convert to ASCII? Or are you trying to parse an ASCII hex dump?

Comment: Oh so i only have this hexdump, excluding the ascii part, after all the hex. All i have are screenshots of the hexdump, for which OCR can only extract the hex, not the ascii representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question well: you want to print ASCII characters from your hex dump that resembles the output of `hexdump`:

```
txt = '''
00000690 52 4D 41 50 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
000006A0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
000006B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
000006C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
000006D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 E0 01 04 90 9B 00 01
000006E0 B9 4D E9 46 5B 43 00 10 B2 BA FB 46 BA 24 13 16
000006F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000700 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '''

for line in txt.splitlines():
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    address, *nums = line.split()

    # printable ascii characters are from 32 to 127, else print a dot '.':
    print('{} {} {}'.format(address, ' '.join(nums), ''.join(chr(int(n, 16)) if 32 <= int(n, 16) <= 127 else '.' for n in nums)))
```

Prints:

```
00000690 52 4D 41 50 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 RMAP............
000006A0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
000006B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
000006C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
000006D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 E0 01 04 90 9B 00 01 ........0.......
000006E0 B9 4D E9 46 5B 43 00 10 B2 BA FB 46 BA 24 13 16 .M.F[C.....F.$..
000006F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000700 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is exactly one space character between two consecutive hexadecimal bytes, and between the offset and the first hexadecimal byte, in the input lines, a bash implementation would be:

```
$  cat hexdump-C 
#!/bin/bash

while read hex; do
# Delete offset
    ascii=" ${hex#* }"
# Replace non-printable bytes with a dot
    ascii=${ascii// [0189ABCDEF]?/.}
# Replace space characters with \x 
    ascii=${ascii// /\\x}
# printf replaces the \xhh sequences with the corresponding characters
    printf "$hex |$ascii|\n"
done
```

--

```
$  cat data
00000690 52 4D 41 50 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  
000006A0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
000006D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 E0 01 04 90 9B 00 01   
000006E0 B9 4D E9 46 5B 43 00 10 B2 BA FB 46 BA 24 13 16 
000006F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   
00000700 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

--

```
$  ./hexdump-C < data
00000690 52 4D 41 50 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 |RMAP............|
000006A0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
000006B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
000006C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
000006D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 30 E0 01 04 90 9B 00 01 |........0.......|
000006E0 B9 4D E9 46 5B 43 00 10 B2 BA FB 46 BA 24 13 16 |.M.F[C.....F.$..|
000006F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
00000700 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
```